# Multiplying specific elements in a 4D array

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python 3 and I have an array `oh_array` which has the shape `(12, 72, 46, 38)` and I need to multiply `[20:27],[38:43],[-16:-1] axis=1` by 10
then `[17:26] axis=2` by 10 and then `[0:8]axis=3` by 10. The array has to stay the same size and dimensions but just have these elements changed in it. I have thought to use a loop with a range but do not know if they can be used in multiple dimensions.

Comment: Hi, for which version of python, 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use [`np.multiply.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) and [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
np.multiply.at(arr, (slice(None), 
                     np.r_[10:28, 38:43, -16:-1], 
                     slice(None), 
                     slice(None)), 
               10)
```

where `arr` is your array. The `ufunc.at` function allows you to multiply values in the indexes (specified in the second argument) or an array `arr` (specified in the first argument) by a certain number `b` (in this case, `10`) specified in the last argument. Just change the indexes accordingly